# Count number of consumer according of numbers of products from product table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product table with columns prodId (product id) and consumer id where prodId is primary key and for each product we have prodId , now for each product we have a consumer as a consumer can have many product , I need to find number number of people according to number of products they have .

[image]

Comment: It does seem a little strange to have a consumer inside a product table, but each to their own, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select numproducts, count(*) as numpeople
from (select consumerid, count(*) as numproducts
      from product
      group by consumerid
     ) c
group by numproducts
order by numproducts;
```